# Can't connect to an mschapv2 network with nmcli after a reboot

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager

I'm having trouble connecting to a wifi network that uses mschapv2 and peap. I was able to before, but after a reboot (changing mac address with ifconfig before the reboot may have something to do with it... I never saved my original mac address but I know that the one it has now isn't the one I changed it to) I am no longer able to. I can connect to open networks, and I followed the answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/262491/connect-to-a-wpa2-enterprise-connection-via-cli-no-desktop and various other places but nothing has helped.

When I run `nmcli con up eduroam2` (eduroam2 is my connection name and uses the wlp3s0 interface) it tries to get the IP configuration for a long time before failing with "Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)". Looking at the journal I see lots of lines saying "connection disconnected (reason -3)" after it switches to the ip-config state.

What could be wrong?

OS: arch

Comment: Maybe the AP does not like your MAC address?

Comment: @RafaelKitover Perhaps. I tried setting the interface's mac address to a known good one, but that still didn't work :/

Comment: Did you do any OS updates before it stopped working? Also eduroam is a source of much grief for linux users in general, have you looked up some eduroam troubleshooting resources?